# Unrar Failing Because Of Space

Tags: archive

I'm trying to unrar a file (i have `unrar-free` package) . 
But it's failed, i think because of files name. File's (which in rar archive) name containing spaces and i can't rename it.

How can i unrar this file?

Note : spaces isn't in archives name, it's in *archived file's* name. For example : **this file should be unrared.flv** file in **test.rar**

```
eray@eray-ubuntu:~/İndirilenler$ unrar terranovas01e06.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/eray/İndirilenler/terranovas01e06.rar

Extracting  Terra Nova - 01x06 - Bylaw.LOL.srt                        Failed    
1 Failed
eray@eray-ubuntu:~/İndirilenler$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unrar-free** seems to have a problem with these files. It *creates a directory* instead of a file when you try to extract the archive.

```
$ unrar-free --list test.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


RAR archive /home/.../test.rar

Pathname/Comment
                  Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 this file should be unrared.flv
                     0        8   0% 10-11-11 18:09   .D....   00000000 m3? 2.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                0        8 inf%
```

Now:

```
$ unrar-free --extract test.rar 

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/.../test.rar

All OK
```

Finally:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ...... ...... 100 2011-11-10 18:12 test.rar
drwxrwxr-x 2 ...... ......   6 2011-11-10 18:27 this file should be unrared.flv
```

Please note the **d** at the first column of the filename.

To extract the file correctly you can use the `unrar` package instead of `unrar-free`.

```
$ unrar x test.rar 

UNRAR 4.00 beta 3 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from test.rar

Extracting  this file should be unrared.flv                           OK 
All OK

$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ...... ...... 100 2011-11-10 18:12 test.rar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ...... ......   0 2011-11-10 18:09 this file should be unrared.flv
```

Comment: using `unrar` instead of `unrar-free` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems until I thought it was corrupted file, the more I began to test all compactors (Bill) and I'd be able to complete the task! Above all files. Rar try using the KDE Ark is the best in my opinion when it comes to files. Rar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html) which, unlike `unrar`, is free software, and it can handle very many other formats (over 150 they say).